# Odoo 8 using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, odoo, odoo-8

I am pretty new to docker. I wanted to make an Odoo 8 container using xcgd/odoo’s image file.
Below is my docker compose file. The web container died with exit code 0 soon after I docker-compose up the yml.

I know that xcgd/odoo requires to link the db container, I’ve seen it in the documentation.

```
$ docker run -p 8069:8069 --rm --name="xcgd.odoo" --link pg93:db xcgd/odoo:7.0 start
```

Am I missing this link in my yaml? I thought I already define the link using `networks`?

Can anyone point my mistake?

My yaml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  # Web Application Service Definition
  # --------
  #
  # All of the information needed to start up an odoo web
  # application container.
  web:
    image: xcgd/odoo:8.0
    depends_on:
        - db

    # Port Mapping
    # --------
    #
    # Here we are mapping a port on the host machine (on the left)
    # to a port inside of the container (on the right.) The default
    # port on Odoo is 8069, so Odoo is running on that port inside
    # of the container. But we are going to access it locally on
    # our machine from localhost:9000.
    #ports:
    #  - 80:8069

    # Data Volumes
    # --------
    #
    # This defines files that we are mapping from the host machine
    # into the container.
    #
    # Right now, we are using it to map a configuration file into
    # the container and any extra odoo modules.
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons/logic:/mnt/logic-addons
      - ./addons/data:/mnt/data-addons

    # Odoo Environment Variables
    # --------

    # The odoo image uses a few different environment
    # variables when running to connect to the postgres
    # database.
    #
    # Make sure that they are the same as the database user
    # defined in the db container environment variables.
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=proc.fullertonhealth.co.id
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8069
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=proc.fullertonhealth.co.id
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@fullertonhealth.co.id

    expose:
      - 8069

  # Database Container Service Definition
  # --------
  #
  # All of the information needed to start up a postgresql
  # container.
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5

    # Database Environment Variables
    # --------
    #
    # The postgresql image uses a few different environment
    # variables when running to create the database. Set the
    # username and password of the database user here.
    #
    # Make sure that they are the same as the database user
    # defined in the web container environment variables.
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres  # Leave this set to postgres

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: You don’t need to declare port level connectivity. Docker compose should be able to get this info from exposed ports of containers. Check your logs to verify if the database connectivity is the actual problem. Please post the actual error you get.

Comment: Hi, it turns out I have to set `command: "start"` in the web service. My bad, I did not understand the parameters of `docker run` example given in the documentation.

Comment: Would you turn your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out I have to set command: "start" in the web service. My bad, I did not understand the parameters of docker run example given in the documentation.